# How do I get the id of an object into a GenericView in Django?

Tags: python, django

Currently, I am at the end of Django and wanted to add a functionality to check whether the Question object being used actually does have any choices. Right now, it will not show off any boxes and give me a 'Vote'-button which is effectively useless because I cannot check off any boxes.

I have tried using the 'pk' keyword that is supposed to be passed on to DetailView when I enter a webpage, as evident here:

```
url(r'^specifics/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

But when I try to use the pk variable in my DetailView, it complains that it does not know any keyword by the name of pk. I get this error in particular: `NameError: name 'pk' is not defined`. In my details.html, I tried to print out `{{ question.pk }}` and that is working flawlessly (however, I suspect it is due to the vote function in views.py).

Here are both DetailView and vote() in my web app:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    question_exist = Question.objects.exists()
    empty_choice = question[pk].choice_query.exists()

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ Exclude any unpublished questions. """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except(KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice!",
            })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return HttpResonseRedirect after POST success, prevents
        # data from being posted twice if someone hits the back button!
        return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id, )) )
```

And here is my detail.html:

```
<h1> {{ question.question_text }} </h1>

{% if error_message %}<p> <strong> {{ error_message }} </strong> </p> {% endif %}
{% if empty_choice %}
        <p> There are no choices!  </p>
{% else %}
        <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"
                        value="{{ choice.id }}"/>
                        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
                        <br />
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
        </form>
{% endif %}
{{ question.pk }}
```

question.pk returns the correct number in each website, but when I try to use it in DetailView, Django says that it doesn't understand what pk it. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to access `pk` when you are defining the class.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
```

This won't work because you don't have access to the `pk` yet. You can access the `pk` in the class methods, when the request is handled.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['empty_choice'] = self.object.choice_query.exists()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ Exclude any unpublished questions. """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

Note that you don't have to get the question using `get_object_or_404` - the [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method of the generic view will take care of that for you.

It would probably be better to name your view something else (e.g. `QuestionDetailView`, so that it doesn't get confused with Django's `DetailView`.

Comment: I got another error after renaming DetailView to QuestionDetailView `Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$']`
I have made sure all instances of DetailView have been replaced with QuestionDetailView, so I really don't see what've happened now.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to `super(QuestionDetailView, self)`. However, when I commented out the get_context_data function, the program works as usual again. I find that very weird.
EDIT: just the presence of the function( the function name and consisting only of pass) triggers the error. Django does not want me to have this function.

Comment: Here is the git-repo of the file: Here is the git-repo for the file https://github.com/wOstensen/my-new-blog

Maybe you see something I can't see. :p

Comment: I see the problem now... we forgot to return context.

Comment: I tried to return context, and now Django says that Question object has no attribute 'choice_query'. :/

Comment: I don't know what that line is supposed to do, I included it because you had `question[pk].choice_query.exists()` in your original question.

Comment: Wow, yeah, using `get_context_data` is smarter.  I believe that with that `choice_query` you wanted to get the `Choice` models as per django tutorial.  In that case `self.object.choice_set.exists()` shall do the job

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `pk` during class construction, it is not there until a request comes in.  Classes are constructed when django is loaded into memory much before any request can be taken.  Basically you cannot use the following lines because django has no clue about a `pk` when they're being executed:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    question_exist = Question.objects.exists()
    empty_choice = question[pk].choice_query.exists()
```

Instead you shall use the `get_queryset` function, which is only called once a request comes in.  The `pk` will be in `self.kwargs` (because you did give it the a name in the URLconf regex):

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ Exclude any unpublished questions. """
        return get_object_or_404( Question,
                                  pk=self.kwargs['pk'],
                                  pub_date__lte=timezone.now() )
```

(This example might have some quirks, i haven't tested it.  Apologies for that.  I'll test it once i get home)

Answer (score 1):

you can access the id,slug etc of an object in a generic view from your get_object()

example

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
   
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        """ Exclude any unpublished questions. """
        id = self.get_object().id
        # put remaining code here
```